# Where are org-publish-project-alist variables and properties documented?

Tags: org-mode, org-publish

I am learning orgmode publishing.
There are some org-publish-project-alist variables and properties I am not finding in the documentation.
Maybe I am looking in the wrong places.
Where else are the following org-publish-project-alist variables and properties documented?
(I tested them in the org-publish-project-alist file listed at the end)

This is used in https://orgmode.org/manual/Simple-example.html#Simple-example:

```
:table-of-contents nil
```

A TOC was generated.

This is listed in https://orgmode.org/manual/Publishing-options.html:

```
:with-toc nil
```

TOC was not generated.

This is used in https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-publish-html-tutorial.html:

```
:publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
```

How is it different than org-publish-org-to-html described in https://orgmode.org/manual/Publishing-action.html ?

Why are these two JavaScript functions generated and not called?

```
function CodeHighlightOn(elem, id)
function CodeHighlightOff(elem, id)
```

This is used in https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-publish-html-tutorial.html:

```
:style "<link rel=\"stylesheet\"
  href=\"../other/mystyle.css\"
  type=\"text/css\"/>"
```

Stylesheet link was not in the generated html file.  How to link to a style sheet?

This is used in https://orgmode.org/manual/HTML-preamble-and-postamble.html#HTML-preamble-and-postamble

```
:org-html-postamble nil
```

Postamble was generated.  How to prevent generating postamble?

Here is the file I used to test org-publish-project-alist:

```
(require 'ox-publish)    ;C-x C-e to load org-publish
(setq org-publish-project-alist
      '(
("org-source"                         ;org-source files to be transformed into html files
 :base-directory "~/Documents/developer/editors/emacs/publish_html/org/"
 :base-extension "org"
 :publishing-directory "~/Documents/developer/editors/emacs/publish_html/public_html/"
 :recursive t
 :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
 :table-of-contents nil               ;nil fail, generated TOC
 :style "<link rel=\"stylesheet\"
      href=\"../other/mystyle.css\"
      type=\"text/css\"/>"            ;style fail, no style link was generated

;properties listed in left column of https://orgmode.org/manual/Publishing-options.html
 :with-toc nil                        ;nil pass, did not generate TOC
 :headline-levels 4
 :section-numbers nil                 ;nil pass, generated headings without sections numbers
 :html-head-include-default-style nil ;nil pass, did not generate 160-lines of commented style
 :org-html-postamble nil              ;nil fail, postamble was generated
 )

("org-static"
 :base-directory "~/Documents/developer/editors/emacs/publish_html/org/"
 :base-extension "css\\|js\\|png\\|jpg\\|gif\\|pdf\\|mp3\\|ogg\\|swf"
 :publishing-directory "~/Documents/developer/editors/emacs/publish_html/public_html/"
 :recursive t
 :publishing-function org-publish-attachment
 )

("org" :components ("org-source" "org-static"))
      ))                 ;C-x C-e and repeat after every change to org-publish-project-alist
;to publish: SPC u SPC SPC org-publish-project
```

Comment: "This is used in https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-publish-html-tutorial.html:

:publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html

How is it different than org-publish-org-to-html described in https://orgmode.org/manual/Publishing-action.html ?" There is no `org-publish-org-to-html` any more: it has been replaced by `org-html-publish-to-html` The manual needs to be fixed.

Comment: I would urge you to post this question on the mailing list: it is an octopus of a question, so it does not fit well into the SE "one question/one answer" paradigm.

Comment: I agree with @NickD. Also worth noting - org is very actively developed, and the tutorials on worg often lag behind, or simply aren't updated when org changes. Best to stick with the main manual, and be aware that even that is sometimes out of date.

Comment: @Tyler, Thanks for the warning.  I don't know elisp so I won't be able to understand org-publish enough to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

org is very actively developed, and the tutorials on worg often lag behind or simply aren't updated when org changes. Best to stick with the main manual, and be aware that even that is sometimes out of date.